# How to format "2015-08-01T06:51:14.000+08:00" to Java Date?

Tags: java, date

It seems a Javascript date in String, but how to format it to a `java.util.Date`? Is it possible by `SimpleDateFormat`?

Okay, I didn't read it carefully.

Comment: You could ve easily tried it and found it out yourself.

Comment: Do you means *parse* the text to a `java.util.Date`, or *format* a `java.util.Date` to text in that format?

Comment: See [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Do you just want to extract the date portion from it, i.e 2015-08-01 ?

Comment: You have not read the javadoc, did you? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the examples mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) exactly matches your case:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"  2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00
```

So

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX").parse(yourString);
```

will give what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern of `javascript` date you are getting is

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"  2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00
```

in terms of `java`.

Use the sample code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
        System.out.println(sdf.parse("2015-08-01T06:51:14.000+08:00"));
        Date date = sdf.parse("2015-08-01T06:51:14.000+08:00");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the API documentation of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (see the examples), the pattern to use in your case is:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"
```

Bear in mind that using Z instead of XXX only works if time zone is written as -0700 (no colon).